# Java :Calling another script

Tags: java

If I were to call script *b* with script *a*(in which it has some parameters, and by that i mean `b(int x, int y)`, is there any way to get around the fact that you have the `public static void main` the place where it starts in the script? 
Here is an example of what my code is like:

Script b

```
public class b{
    public b(){
        new a(4,4);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new b();
    }
}
```

Script a

```
public class a{
    public a(int x, int y){...}
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new a();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get it. Can you please clarify? Why do you even need `main` in `a`?/ Why it is not needed at all?

Comment: Uhm.. Running class B is creating a new instance of B, which is creating a new instance of A, which you then forget about? That's like doing a lot of things without getting anything done.

Comment: I did not get it too.

Comment: So if you call another script, you don't actually need `main`?